# How propertly clear file in linux

Tags: c++, linux, file-descriptor

Good day, i open file to write to it some content.Code below:

```
class file_worker
{
public:
    file_worker(const std::string &path):path_(path),stop_(false)
    {
        umask(0);
        file_descriptor_ = open(path_.c_str(),O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
    }
    void operator()()
    {
        if(file_descriptor_!=-1)
        {
             clear_file();
            //write something
        }
    }
    void clear_file()
    {

    }
    ~file_worker()
    {
        if(file_descriptor_!=-1)
        {
            close(file_descriptor_);
        }
    }
private:
    const std::string path_;
    int file_descriptor_;
    bool stop_;
};
```

How can implement clear_file(); function that it will be possible to clear(remove all file content) without closing file descriptor? Which way are to faster write to file is? Is it possible write to file of some threads simultaneously with in different parts of the file (use lseek may be)?

Comment: You should test the success of `open` in the constructor, and probably use `perror` when it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define what clearing a file means to you.

You could shrink the file to a 0 size, use [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) for that.

You could zero all the bytes in the file. Then, use [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) with `write(2)` or perhaps [pwrite(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html)

There could be issues if some other process is writing the file at the same time (which is bad practice).

I am not sure that using multi-threading will really speed up that zeroing of all bytes. (doing this is disk-intensive unless the system file cache is hit, and multi-threading won't speed up disk), so I would benchmark first.

Comment: No only one process can write, but may be increase write-speed if i use threads with lseek functionality?